# KDE installed but no package manager?

Tags: kde

I've installed KDE on CentOS 7.2 though I can't find Yast or determine there to be any package manager available. What is the current default package manager or how do I install one for KDE?

Comment: Dont you mean yum? I am pretty sure Yast is opensuse Yast is unique to suse so its not used anywhere else.

Comment: @DylanRz I used KDE about two or three years ago and it included a package manager. I know how to use yum on the terminal but I'm not using KDE to use the terminal.

Comment: There is gpk-application which is the GNOME Package Manager. But I am not sure if that gets installed if you run KDE, There is always alternatives like yumex.

Comment: CentOS uses Yum

Answer (score 0):

Yum Extender (Yumex) installation from the terminal:

```
yum install yumex
yumex --root
```

If you start Yumex in KDE (probably other desktop environments as well) but it doesn't open after about 10 seconds then it's because it's complaining about you being logged on as root so to launch Yumex as root use the second command from the terminal.